# How can I use a CSS stylesheet that is up 2 directories from the file where I am trying to access it from?

Tags: html, css, relative-path

I am trying to use a CSS stylesheet that is up 2 directories and inside another folder:

```
--project
  --css
    --main.css
  --views
    --shop
      --products.php
```

I need to go from products.php to main.css

As far as I'm aware, it should be `../../css/main.css`. but it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated, I'm using Chrome if that makes a difference.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css"/>
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is not working because `products.php` is not being loaded by the browser two levels deep into the site. But something like `example.com/products.php`. Many sites will use absolute URLs or root relative URLs. A root relative URL starts with a slash `/`. The browser will start searching for the CSS file from the root of the site instead of based on the URL path location of the page that was loaded. In your case, use `/css/main.css'`. There are other ways to get around this but is out of scope.

Comment: At what url you are accessing the `product.php`...?

Comment: `../../css/main.css` will not work for `abc.com/products.php` as you cannot go up two directories. It will not work for `abc.com/alpha/beta/charlie/products.php` as going up two directories places you in the `alpha` directory. Which does not contain the `css` directory.

Comment: @hungerstar, I've just tried using /css/main.css, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @vaku, the url is http://localhost/project/fashionshop/views/shop/products.php

Comment: Ok, that actually is working now, but the specific styling I have just done isn't showing.  `.products {border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:20px; min-height:545.96px;}` 

`<div class="products">`

Is there a syntax error I'm not seeing?

Comment: Did absolute path works...?

Comment: @NathanJanman that's because you're on `localhost`. If you had this on a server with a domain it would work. `localhost` behaves as folder unless you change some server settings for your localhost. Right now it's looking for a `css` folder inside `/localhost` instead of a `css` folder inside of `/project`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would place your CSS and JS files in the "webroot" folder of your application. This is the location that your end users will be able to access. Inside this folder would also be the entry point for your PHP application.

So when I connect to www.example.com, I am connecting to their webroot folder:
project/webroot/index.php
and their CSS could be in:
project/webroot/css/main.css

This is done for security as allowing an end user to traverse through your source files will likely reveal vulnerabilities (such as a database address, username and password!).

Keep in mind when making files accessible they need to be available from the client, not just the server!

Comment: So you're saying that my css and js files should be placed in the project folder (if using the folder path as in the question)?

Comment: Reffering to one of your comments, you state you are testing this from localhost/project/fashionshop/views/shop/products.php. As such I would put CSS and JS inside of your views folder. I am judging this based on the MVC design pattern (Model, View, Controller), where the view is responsible for design.
However I would rethink how the client interacts with your application, as they should not be able to connect with many of these php files.

Comment: Resources like CSS, JS, images, etc should NOT be a views folder. They are typically stored outside the MVC folders.

Comment: Normally they are but looking at the OP's folder structure this does not seem to apply.